# SharePoint 2013 Popularity Trends and Most Popular Missing for List

Tags: 2013, blog, web-analytics

According to [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715890.aspx) I should be able to view Popularity Trends for Lists:

> 3.Select the item that you want to view the Popularity Trends report for, and then do one of the following:
>
> - For a library, click the **FILES** tab, and then, on the ribbon, click **Popularity Trends**.
> - For a list, click the **ITEMS** tab, and then, on the ribbon, click **Popularity Trends**.

In my case this is true for Libraries but the Popularity Trends button in the ribbon seems to be missing for Lists in the ITEMS tab? It is the same of Most Popular Items in the LIST tab.

I am specifically trying to get Usage Reports for a SharePoint 2013 Blog Site.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: I've also seen this behavior. Still not sure of the solution, but will keep looking. Know that you're neither crazy, nor alone.

Comment: I'm experiencing this EXACT problem! I can generate 'Popularity Trends' and 'Most Popular Items' in document libraries, but I'm seeing nothing in lists (be it blog posts or custom lists containing content types inheriting from items). Can anyone please advise? Thank you.

Comment: Still no resolution on this unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

From the same article you linked to:

> Note: Usage reports are only available for Document Libraries and Product Catalog lists.

I don't want to believe that's true, but it seems to match the observed behaviour of SharePoint 2013 :-(

Answer (score 1):

Directly from Microsoft Premiere Support, "the Most Popular reports for blogs is not supported regardless of activating the Cross-Site Collection Publishing feature."

Another home run for Microsoft. #smh

Answer (score 1):

You can apparently force SharePoint to understand lists as "Product Catalog lists" by activating the Cross-Site Collection Publishing feature in Site Collection Features.  Once this feature is activated, the Most Popular Items button appears on the LIST tab and the Popularity Trends button appears on the ITEMS tab whichever list you look at.

Answer (score -3):

You need to activate SharePoit feature of Reporting then results available