# Most Popular Items not visible on the toolbar

Tags: sharepoint-online, popularity-trends

I figured out that SharePoint online has this feature where you can check the **Most Popular Items** inside a document library

Based on the articles that I've read the toolbar should look like this

[image]

However, this is how my toolbar is lookiing . Most Popular Items is missing

[image]

How do I activate this feature ?

Tis is a picture of how my site settings window looks like

[image: e]

Comment: is this a modern site that you are using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate the "Reporting" feature under Site Settings -> Site Collection Features

Comment: is it written as  __Duet Enterprise Reporting__

Comment: Just as Reporting

Comment: after going to Site Settings, i can't find Site Collection Features

Comment: You need to be a Site Collection Administrator

Comment: as fire as I know I have all the rights . Is there a way I can check if Im a site collection administrator ?

Comment: If you are a Site Collection Administrator then you should see "Site Collection Administration" header and setting links under that just like - "Users and Permissions", "Look and Feel", "Site Actions", etc. If not then you are not the Site Collection Administrator and you will not be able to check who is.

Comment: I added a picture of how my site settings window looks like

Comment: You are not a site collection Administrator.

Comment: mark your answer as solved, thank u. I just have a question regarding what if my site is using modern expereince . Does the modern expereince has a top most viewed option where all users can access. I want this so users use that and out of tohusands of files they get a list of the files that are viewed the most

Comment: No there is no top ribbon in modern SharePoint. For that you can create a button using SPFx or you can create a page and try some available web parts on modern page like highlighted content and all.

Comment: do you have any articles or post which elaborate more in this?

Comment: how many items would the Most Popular Items show ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Most Popular Items and Popularity Trends options missing for Lists -SharePoint Online](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointsearch/2015/07/20/most-popular-items-and-popularity-trends-options-missing-for-lists-sharepoint-online/).

> In order to see “Most popular Items” option for list enable the Cross Site publishing feature by going to Site settings-> Site collection features. Once you enable this you will be able to see the option.

However, according to [SharePoint Online Service Description](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-service-description), Cross-Site publishing feature is supported only in:

1. SharePoint Online Plan 2
2. Office 365 Enterprise E3 and Office 365 Enterprise E5
3. SharePoint Server 2016 Enterprise

You can check your subscription using [What Office 365 business product or license do I have?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-Office-365-business-product-or-license-do-I-have-f8ab5e25-bf3f-4a47-b264-174b1ee925fd)

Check the similar question asked on community:

1. [How to - Cross site publishing in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163341/how-to-cross-site-publishing-in-sharepoint-online)
2. Try activating **Reporting** feature at site collection level if it is not already activated as given in: [SharePoint 2013 Popularity Trends and Most Popular Missing for List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90488/sharepoint-2013-popularity-trends-and-most-popular-missing-for-list/128060#128060)